# NASA GMAT Hardware in the Loop testing

Tags: nasa, mission-design, testing, gmat, simulator

We are currently evaluating various Mission Analysis & Simulation tools, one of which is NASA's GMAT (2020). One of our requirements is for the tool to support HITL testing. However, i am unable to find anything in the docs regarding the feasibility of this.

Specifically, we want to be able to hook up our test satellite to the simulator in order to facilitate the following:

1. Override the satellites sensor values with values from the simulator
2. The corresponding control response from satellite should be reflected back to simulator

Is this something that is supported out of the box, or requires customization?

Comment: I do not believe GMAT has anything built in for HITL testing. It is more focused on mission analysis that flight software. I would take a look at opensatkit and some of the constituent software that it uses: https://github.com/OpenSatKit/OpenSatKit/wiki